Is "continuous arithmetic mean" operator bounded in $L_2$ spaces?
Suppose $T: L_2 \to L_2$ is defined by the following equality:
$$Tf(x) = \frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x} f(t) dt$$
In other words, we're examining a continuous arithmetic mean operator.
It is then claimed that $T$ is a bounded operator, i.e. there exists a constant $C$, such that
$$ \|Tf\|_2^2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt \right)^2dx \leq C \cdot\int_0^{\infty} |f(x)|^2dx  = C \cdot \|f\|_2^2$$ for all $f\in L_2(\mathbb{R}_+)$.
I am personally not 100% sure as to whether the statement is actually true, but it seems to be likely, as I haven't managed to find a counter-example.
This also appears to be quite similar to Cesaro summability (hence the tag), but the connection isn't that clear to me. I am also curious as to whether this holds for $L_p$ spaces in general for values $p \not = 2$.

Your operator can be written in the form
$$
(Tf)(x)=\int_{0}^\infty K(x,t)f(t) \ \mathrm dt,
$$
where $K$ is a measurable function.
Consider $w(t)=t^{-\alpha}$ for $\alpha>0$. For appropriately chosen $\alpha$ there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\int_0^\infty |K(x,t)|w(t) \ \mathrm dt \leq Cw(x)
$$
for almost every $x\in (0,\infty)$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty |K(x,t)|w(x) \ \mathrm dx \leq Cw(t)
$$
for almost every $t\in (0,\infty)$. Therefore for $f\in L^2(0,\infty)$ we have
$$
\left(\int_0^\infty |K(x,t)|\cdot |f(t)| \ \mathrm d t\right)^2 \leq Cw(x)\int_{0}^\infty |K(x,t)|\frac{|f(t)|^2}{w(t)} \ \mathrm dt.
$$
You can use this to show that $K$ is a bounded kernel, i.e. we have
$$
\int_0^\infty\left(\int_0^\infty |K(x,t)|\cdot|f(t)| \ \mathrm dt\right)^2 \ \mathrm d x\leq C^2 \lVert f\rVert_2^2.
$$
It should then be straight forward to show that $T$ is indeed a bounded operator $L^2(0,\infty)\to L^2(0,\infty)$.

That's pretty much the story in some greater generality. For the concrete problem at hand we have $K(x,t)=1_{(0,x)}(t)\cdot \frac 1x$. With $\alpha=1/2$ and $w$ as above we have
$$
\int_0^\infty K(x,t)w(t) \ \mathrm d t=\frac{1}{1-\alpha} x^{-\alpha}=2w(x)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^\infty K(x,t)w(x) \ \mathrm d x=\frac 1\alpha t^{-\alpha}=2w(t),
$$
so that $C=2$ and $\alpha=1/2$ will do the trick.

That more or less answers my question, thank you!
However I don't quite understand which $\alpha$ and $C$ we actually choose for the Schur test to be applicable.

@Confused $C=2$ and $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}$ will work.
